# Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081448) - Error 0x80073712

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have updated my notebook from windows 8.1 to windows 10. Now when ever i am trying to update i am getting this error.

> "Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081448) -
>   Error 0x80073712"

I have tried troubleshooting, dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
sfc /scannnow, etc given in this link
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/cumulative-update-for-windows-10-for-x64-based/249c550d-274a-4fc0-b2de-ba0503941b1d?auth=1

But no luck issue remains unresolved.
[image]

Comment: When you issued the two commands `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannnow` what did you get result.  Post your results and the log file for us.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added screenshot of result

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip the folder and upload the zip.

Comment: [See #2 in Step 2 for W8, you have to use an external source to repair it using dism](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957310)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run this [Microsoft solution](https://solutions.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/run/d472835f-9d3b-4677-a186-40983f5bbc3d#).

Take backups first and create a system restore point.

Comment: ---------------------------  
Init-219c96cf-466e-4516-8648-3562b9c0cdc4.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because MSVCR120.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
Getting this error. even i can see MSVCR120.dl inside windows/system32 folder

Comment: Bravo Microsoft. msvcr120.dll is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 that you can [download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Click the Download button and check both `vcredist_x*.exe` and install first the x86 one and, then the x64 if it wasn't the right one (they don't conflict).

Answer (score 0):

I ever had the same issue but with different cumulative update, I suggest you to go to Program and Features to uninstall the previous update that has been installed by windows update before you get the (KB3081448). After that run windows update again, Hopefully it will restore the previous update state and reinstall the latest updates successfully.

Comment: A comment by [Edgardo L. Juelar](http://superuser.com/users/491822/edgardo-l-juelar): _Cuki is correct! since this update intends to replace the previous KB..144 but because of something in that KB..144, KB...148 cannot continue, find the KB...144 update and uninstall it so you can download the KB...148. This solved my problem on this...Hope yours too. good luck!_